# FileUpload in angularjs

Tags: c#, file-upload, angular-file-upload

I'm using `angular-file-upload` as found in [Here](https://github.com/nervgh/angular-file-upload). It was working for what I needed, but now the need has changed, and I'd like to be able to send additional data about (object) along with the file. There isn't much documentation about it. With what I could see, when I used `options` directive as attribute and provided the data as object, it's not listed anywhere in FileUploader. Also, my controller gives me an error when I upload. I added a Model class in `Post` as argument, which is what causing the controller to break.

```
    [HttpPost]

    public Task<HttpResponseMessage> PostFile(QAFileAttribute QAFile)
    {
        this.QAFile = QAFile;
        string newLocation = GetCurrentUploadDirectory();

        HttpRequestMessage request = this.Request;
        if(!request.Content.IsMimeMultipartContent())
        {
            throw new HttpResponseException(HttpStatusCode.UnsupportedMediaType);
        }

        string root = UploadLocation; //newLocation;

        var provider = new MultipartFormDataStreamProvider(root);

        var task = request.Content.ReadAsMultipartAsync(provider)
            .ContinueWith<HttpResponseMessage>(o =>
            {
                if (o.IsFaulted || o.IsCanceled)
                {
                    Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError, o.Exception);
                }

                foreach (MultipartFileData file in provider.FileData)
                {
                    if(String.IsNullOrEmpty(file.Headers.ContentDisposition.FileName))
                    {
                        return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.NotAcceptable, "Filename is not acceptable.");
                    }

                    UploadFile(file, QAFile);                        
                }

                return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
            });

        return task;
    }// end Post
```

So, how can I send the multi-part file along with additional data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out myself. This [link](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/advanced/sending-html-form-data-part-2) helped a lot. Turned out, I didn't have to do a whole lot to provide additional data. I just needed to provide formData as request body to be processed inside the action; the controller action doesn't take any parameters. The problem with my code was that (I want to say due to improper documentation of angular-file-upload) I had misunderstood what formData is. Turned out, it's array of objects. It needed to be like this:

```
var uploader = new FileUploader({
  url: 'api/upload',
  formData: [{...}]

});
```

This sent the data to the controller action as request body. From there, I just had to access it as `provider.FormData["somename"];`

Answer (score 0):

This link will sure help you , I have implemented this. 
https://uncorkedstudios.com/blog/multipartformdata-file-upload-with-angularjs

```
app.service('fileUpload', ['$http', function ($http) {
this.uploadFileToUrl = function(file, additional, uploadUrl){
    var fd = new FormData();
    fd.append('file', file);

    $.each(additional, function(obj) {
         fd.append(obj.key,obj.value);
    });
    $http.post(uploadUrl, fd, {
        transformRequest: angular.identity,
        headers: {'Content-Type': undefined}
    })
    .success(function(){
    })
    .error(function(){
    });
}
```

}]);

Comment: Ok, it might, I'm not sure. But the other part of the question still remains unanswered - How do in send in additional data and make the controller accept it along with the file?

Comment: The issue wasn't with how to upload the file. The issue was with how to provide more data along with the file, and have the controller process it.

Comment: fd.append('file', file); statement you can add additional data.